# Space between subcaptions

Tags: spacing, graphics, subcaption

so there is a lot of topics with spaces between subcaptions and captions etc. but my problem is a bit different. I have two subfiugures and the text is so long that it fills the `0.5\linewidth` that I set the subfigure to have. The subcaptions though are next to each other without any space between, is there a way to control it?

```
\begin{figure}[ht]
\centering
\begin{subfigure}{.5\textwidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=0.9\linewidth]{picture1}
    \caption{long text (couple lines) that is so long that it fills the caption space and has no separation from the text in the second subfigure}
    \label{fig:label1}
\end{subfigure}%
\begin{subfigure}{.5\textwidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=0.9\linewidth]{picture2}
    \caption{long text (couple lines) that is so long that it fills the caption space and has no separation from the text in the second subfigure}
    \label{fig:label2}
\end{subfigure}
\caption{Short text.}
\label{fig:labl}
\end{figure}
```

Thank you!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you

- change both

  ```
  \begin{subfigure}{.5\textwidth}
  ```

  directives to

  ```
  \begin{subfigure}{.475\textwidth}
  ```
- change the

  ```
  \includegraphics[width=0.9\linewidth]{...}
  ```

  directives to

  ```
  \includegraphics[width=1\linewidth]{...}
  ```
- omit the now-redundant `\centering` instructions
- last but not least, change

  ```
  \end{subfigure}%
  ```

  to

  ```
  \end{subfigure}\hfill
  ```

  The `\hfill` instruction (short for "horizontal fill") maximizes the horizontal separation of the `subfigure` environments (and their contents -- the graphs and captions).

Comment: Worked like a charm thanks so much!